# Mac programming: Get highlighted text in an application?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to try out some Mac programming by making a simple background app that records all the history of the text users highlight in other applications, whether it's in PDF, word document, or web page (sounds silly but it's quite useful for me). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in the general case, and insanely tricky even when considering applications one at a time. It can be achieved for some apps with code injection (but this is insanely fragile), and could be done in theory for some apps using AppleScript (but only if the app helps you).

Much more common is to create [Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/Articles/menu.html), which allow you to integrate with other apps pasteboards (with user intervention). But almost no apps expose APIs to their highlighting.

---

@nielsbot asks an interesting question, and perhaps that's an approach. You'd call `AXUIElementCreateSystemWide` to create a system-wide accessibility object, and then add yourself as an observer waiting for `kAXSelectedTextChangedNotification`. That would likely work for accessible apps (which is most apps that use standard widgets). So it's worth investigating.

Comment: can you do it with the accessibility APIs?

Comment: I looked into Accessibility API and tried using Accessibility Inspector to inspect the UIs of some common apps like Chrome, SublimeText. There weren't much information about selected text in those apps. I wonder how Apple-made apps like Dictionary does it.

Comment: Dictionary generally uses a Service. Just selecting text doesn't cause the Dictionary app to change its information.